# Convert panel.widgets.tables.Tabulator to layoutDOM

Tags: bokeh, tabulator, pandas-bokeh, tabulator-py

I'm new to Bokeh so apologies if I get the terminology wrong.

I have a simple dashboard and I'm trying to add a chart using tabulator to the page [docs](https://pyviz-dev.github.io/panel/reference/widgets/Tabulator.html)

The basic setup is as follows

```js
from bokeh.models import Select, Panel  
from bokeh.models.widgets import Tabs

import my_func from irrelevant_code 

chart = my_func()  # this is a tabulator object

tab1 = Panel(child = summary_layout, title="Summary") 
tab2 = Panel(child = chart, title="Chart")
tabs = Tabs(tabs=[tab1, tab2])

document = curdoc()
document.add_root(tabs)
```

This runs into a problem since `Panel` expects a `LayoutDOM` object and chart is a `panel.widgets.tables.Tabulator` object.

How can I convert chart to a layoutDOM object?

The specific error I get is

```
*** ValueError: failed to validate Panel(id='1212', ...).child: expected an instance of type LayoutDOM, got Tabulator(formatters={'testDate': DateForm...}, groups={'testGroup': ['col1',...}, selectable='checkbox', selection=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...], titles={'col1': 'Column 1', ...}, value=   val1 val2 v...) of type Tabulator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So while in theory you could use the `.get_root()` or `.get_model()` methods on the Tabulator to turn the Panel object into a Bokeh object I would generally recommend just sticking with Panel, e.g. your example can be written as:

```py
import panel as pn

import my_func from irrelevant_code 

chart = my_func()  # this is a tabulator object

tabs = pn.Tabs(('Summary', summary_layout), ('Chart', chart))

tabs.servable()
```